# How to save armature orientation on export to GLB

Tags: armature, export, gltf

I am being asked to work on a rigged model, but I've never used the GLB format before and I'm struggling with the armature. The original model and bones look like this when I import the original file:

[image: aligned_bones]

But when I export it again (without making any changes), the armature looks like this for some reason (every bone has been rotated by what seems like 90 degrees):

[image: sideways_bones] [image: deformed_mesh]

The mesh weight painting still applies and the model will animate, but it's all deformed.

These are my export settings, I've tried fiddling with the Y-Axis and Apply Modifiers setting, but they haven't seemed to change much.

[image: export_settings]

I have read that there were export issues with earlier versions, but I'm using Blender version 2.92.0 on Mac. Any suggestions or advice would be appreciated.

UPDATE (03 Nov 2022): Still struggling with this issue, I found an "answer" in the discussion of this Github issue: https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO/issues/1662
The method suggested is obviously not a sane workflow, so if there's any missing information out there, your insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Update: I found that if I import the GLB model with "Bone Dir" set to "Blender," and then export with "+Y Up" checked, it exports correctly. However this is a very difficult way to work because in the viewport, all the bones are rotated orthogonal to the model they're rigging. :(

Comment: (1) Try upgrading to latest beta (3.2), since the glTF exporter changed a lot since 2.92. (2) Attach the glTF file.